# Laravel many to many eager loading always returns empty results

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

I am trying to fetch all classes of Entry with some condition on it's attributes. One relationship, tags, should be eager loaded.

The models looks like so

```
class Tag extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'tags';
    protected $guarded = array();
    public function entries()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Entry');
    }
}

class Entry extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'entries';
    protected $guarded = array();
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Tag');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

    public function votes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Votes');
    }
}
```

Table entry_tag with dual foreign keys, entry_id,tag_id, exists.

I am trying to use this code.
**(1)**

```
$testEntries = Entry::with(array('tags' => function($query)
{
    $query->where('tag_id', '=', '1');
}))->get();
```

however, it returns nothing. 
even using the code below yields completely zilch.
**(2)**

```
$testEntries = Entry::with('tags')->get();
```

Inspecting the DB log, I can see that the queries are OK. They yield 
**(3)**

```
select `tags`.*, `entry_tag`.`entry_id` as `pivot_entry_id`, `entry_tag`.`tag_id` as `pivot_tag_id` from `tags` inner join `entry_tag` on `tags`.`id` = `entry_tag`.`tag_id` where `entry_tag`.`entry_id` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)","bindings":["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"]
```

and
**(4)**

```
select `tags`.*, `entry_tag`.`entry_id` as `pivot_entry_id`, `entry_tag`.`tag_id` as `pivot_tag_id` from `tags` inner join `entry_tag` on `tags`.`id` = `entry_tag`.`tag_id` where `entry_tag`.`entry_id` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) and `tag_id` = ?","bindings":["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","1"]
```

which both work (and finds results) when executing the queries manually.

What am I missing? I've scratched my head a few hours now!

**EDIT:**

I've tried displaying the results, without any luck, like below

```
Log::debug('testing fetching entries:: ' . json_encode($testEntries));
```

and

```
foreach(Entry::with('tags')->get() as $entry)
        {
            Log::debug('test1!! ' . json_encode($entry));           
        }
```

**EDIT 2:**
I have tried fetching Tags with their entries, like so

```
Tag::with('entries')->get();
```

but it (along with other combinations) returns zero results every time. I am thinking maybe I have missed something fundamental in the way I have set up tables. Here is the complete sql output for attempt **(2)**, in case it helps.

```
{"query":"select * from `entries`","bindings":[],"time":0.33},{"query":"select `tags`.*, `entry_tag`.`entry_id` as `pivot_entry_id`, `entry_tag`.`tag_id` as `pivot_tag_id` from `tags` inner join `entry_tag` on `tags`.`id` = `entry_tag`.`tag_id` where `entry_tag`.`entry_id` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)","bindings":["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8"],"time":0.74}
```

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but try to define your BelongsToMany() relationships like this: `return $this->belongsToMany('Entry', 'entry_tag', 'entry_id', 'tag_id');` and vice versa in the Entry table

Comment: How are you attempting to display the results?  Maybe there is a typo there somewhere.

Comment: @GladToHelp, no change. Since it currently creates the successful sql queries (looking at the DB log) it makes sense that it's no difference.

Comment: @user1669496 I added the information to the question.

Comment: @C-A Does it work when you try to fetch a single entry without filtering or eager loading? Something like `$testEntries = Entry::find(1);` ?

Comment: @GladToHelp Yep works, `Entry::find(X);` and `Entry::all();` both gives back expected results.

Comment: @C-A have you managed to resolve this by now?

Comment: @GladToHelp no unfortunately not, I am using a raw query instead. I've chugged it down to being a typo error somewhere. Next project I'll set this up immediately and try to get it working, to see if it's my local machine or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you use soft delete trait, check `deleted_at` has default value `NULL`.